# Twisted cubic as a plane section of the Segre threefold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, problem-solving, projective-geometry

As usual, I have not a clue on how to tackle excercises our instructor assigns from Harris. The fact is that, at least to me, Harris is very concise and do not really builds the ''mindset'' to do solve this problems.

It is asked to show that the twisted cubic $C\subset\mathbb{P}^3$ can be realized as the itersection of the Segre threefold $\Sigma_{1,2}\subset\mathbb{P}^5$ with a 3-plane $\mathbb{P}^3\subset\mathbb{P}^5$

I know that $\Sigma_{1,1}=V(x_0x_3-x_1x_2)$ and that I can write $\Sigma_{2,1}=V(x_0x_3-x_1x_2;x_2x_5-x_4x_3;x_0x_5-x_1x_4)$
while the twisted cubic as
$C=V(x_0x_3-x_1x_2; x_1x_3-{x_2}^2; x_0x_2-{x_1}^2)$.

So both surfaces are in the zero locus of the quadric $x_0x_3-x_1x_2$. What I would neeed then is a 3-plane embodying the two constraints $x_1x_3={x_2}^2; x_0x_2={x_1}^2$ do these two equations define a 3-plane in $\mathbb{P}^5$?

Comment: ["No clue"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions) questions with no work are unlikely to attract answers or help. Please peruse the linked post for what you can do when you have no clue, and then add this to your post.

Comment: How do you know I have done no work? I really have worked through the book, and as I mentioned I simply do not know where to start. Haven't you experienced this before? An hint is truly what I need and I wouldn't have spent time writing a question if I could have avoided

Comment: The post contains no work on the problems. If you read the linked post, you can identify where to start: write things down and play with examples. Can you write down three skew lines that have a nice form and then identify the lines which meet all three? Can you write down the ideal of the twisted cubic? Can you write down the image of the Segre threefold? What do you see when you do these things?

Comment: @kReiser have followed your advice: as you can see there is not much there. Moreover, I couldn't get started without your hints, and I have no idea if what I wrote has the least sense, Hope that now you can understand better my situation. Thanks anyhow

Comment: Good, this question is better for it. Given that you've split off the [skew lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3450568/find-the-lines-which-meet-three-skew-projective-lines-in-mathbbp3) in to their own question, it might be best to make this question only about the twisted cubic. [Your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3445630/any-projective-variety-can-be-seen-as-a-plane-section-of-the-veronese-variety-h) and the comment there will be useful too.

Comment: Ok, it should be better now

Comment: The exercises in Harris are so difficult and disconnected from the text that "I have no clue" is a perfectly normal reaction to them. Harris  [who, sadly, cannot be downvoted :-)] is to blame and not the poor student trying to plough through that book. The paradox is that the book is chock-full of extremely interesting topics: so read it, enjoy it, but don't be unsettled by the exercises...

Comment: Thanks! The problem is our instructor thinks we should be able to do them! But I will find a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're really quite close to the solution now that you've written things down.

> $\Sigma_{2,1}=V(x_0x_3-x_1x_2;x_2x_5-x_4x_3;x_0x_5-x_1x_4)$
>   while the twisted cubic as
>   $C=V(x_0x_3-x_1x_2; x_1x_3-{x_2}^2; x_0x_2-{x_1}^2)$.

Can we impose some linear conditions so that the last equations match the first equations?

Hint:

> Intersecting with a 3-plane is equivalent to enforcing two linear conditions. We notice that $x_4$ and $x_5$ appear in the first equations but not the second, so enforcing two linear relations of the form $x_4=\sum_{i=0}^{i=3} c_ix_i$ and $x_5=\sum_{i=0}^{i=3} d_ix_i$ would let us eliminate $x_4$ and $x_5$ via intersecting with a 3-plane. What relations should we impose?

Full solution:

> If we enforce $x_4=x_1$ and $x_5=x_2$, we get that the equations for $\Sigma_{2,1}$ turn in to $V(x_0x_3-x_1x_2, x_2^2-x_1x_3, x_0x_2-x_1^2)$ which after flipping the sign on the second equation exactly match the equations of the twisted cubic. Since $V(x_1=x_4,x_2=x_5)$ determines a copy of $\Bbb P^3$, we see that our intersection $V(x_0x_3-x_1x_2;x_2x_5-x_4x_3;x_0x_5-x_1x_4)\cap V(x_1=x_4,x_2=x_5)$ exactly gives us a copy of the twisted cubic.