# Find the lines which meet three skew projective lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, problem-solving, projective-geometry, projective-space

Let $L,M,N$ be skew lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$ am asked to find the lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$ which meet all three these lines.

I think that, being lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$ the projectivization of two-dimensional spaces, we can write, up to projective equivalence
$L=[a_0:a_1:0:0]$
$M=[0:0:b_1:b_2]$
$N=[c_0:c_1:c_0:c_1]$
where the indexes $a_i,b_i,c_i$ are never simultaneously $0$.
Now I am lead to think that a projective line meeting all the three should  be of the form $[d_0:d_1:d_2:d_3]$ with all $d_i$ different from $0$.
But this does not seem a line either!
How can I solve this problem ? What can we say in general about skew $k$-planes in $\mathbb{P}^{2k-1}$?

Comment: Your lines are not skew: $M$ meets both $L$ and $N$ in a point.

Comment: Of course. Now I got it right?

Comment: $N$ is not a line as currently written - you need to impose two additional linear conditions on the $c_i$.

Comment: Ok, now N is given by two free parameters and I hope it is a line skew from the other two!